# Golang: using multiple tickers cases in single select blocks entire loop

Tags: go, concurrency, ticker

I have a requirements where I need to do multiple things (irrelevant here) at some regular intervals. I achieved it using the code block mentioned below -

```
func (processor *Processor) process() {
    defaultTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second*2)
    updateTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second*5)
    heartbeatTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second*5)
    timeoutTicker := time.NewTicker(30*time.Second)
    refreshTicker := time.NewTicker(2*time.Minute)
    defer func() {
        logger.Info("processor for ", processor.id, " exited")
        defaultTicker.Stop()
        timeoutTicker.Stop()
        updateTicker.Stop()
        refreshTicker.Stop()
        heartbeatTicker.Stop()
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-defaultTicker.C:
            // spawn some go routines
        case <-updateTicker.C:
            // do something
        case <-timeoutTicker.C:
            // do something else
        case <-refreshTicker.C:
            // log
        case <-heartbeatTicker.C:
            // push metrics to redis
        }
    }
}
```

But I noticed that every once in a while, my *for select* loop gets **stuck** somewhere and I cannot seem to find where or why. By **stuck** I mean I stop receiving refresh ticker logs. But it starts working again normally in some time (5-10 mins)

I have made sure that all operations within each ticker completes within very little amount of time (~0ms, checked by putting logs).

My questions:

1. Is using multiple tickers in single select a good/normal practice (honestly I did not find many examples using multiple tickers online)
2. Anyone aware of any known issues/pitfalls where tickers can block the loop for longer duration.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Based on the information you provided, the likeliest cause is that one of the cases is taking longer than you expect.

Comment: What is the advantage of having all these tickers handled by single `select` instead of separate goroutines per ticker? If you are performing some long-running operation as a part of e.g. `refreshTicker`, no other ticker will be handled until this operation is finished.

Comment: @aquaman Did you solve the issue? I would be interested in the cause and solution.

Comment: @Juve Yes, I was able to resolve it. The problem was with one of the functions called inside "case". We use tickers to process an LRU at regular intervals, the implementation of LRU was not correct leading to an infinite loop in some cases :( After fixing the issue, no more problems with the tickers :)

Comment: Good to hear @aquaman. I just posted my longer answer to your questions in general, but wanted to wait until you confirmed my assumptions. I hope it helps to understand the topic better.

Answer (score 1):

Go does not provide any smart draining behavior for multiple channels, e.g., that older messages in one channel would get processed earlier than more recent messages in other channels. Anytime the loop enters the `select` statement a random channel is chosen.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645808/how-does-select-work-when-multiple-channels-are-involved) and read the part about `GOMAXPROCS=1`. This could be related to your issue. The issue could also be in your logging package. Maybe the logs are just delayed.
In general, I think the issue must be  in your `case` statements. Either you have a blocking function or some dysfunctional code. (**Note**: confirmed by the OP)

But to answer your questions:

**1. Is using multiple tickers in single select a good/normal practice?**

It is common to read from multiple channels randomly in a **blocking** way, one message at a time, e.g., to sort incoming data from multiple channels into a slice or map and avoid concurrent data access.
It is also common to add one or more tickers, e.g., to flush data and for logging or reporting. Usually the non-ticker code paths will do most of the work.

In your case, you use tickers that will run code paths that **should block** each other, which is a very specific use case but may be required in some scenarios. This uncommon, but not bad practice I think.
As the commenters suggested, you could also schedule different recurring tasks in separate goroutines.

**2. Is anyone aware of any known issues/pitfalls where tickers can block the loop for longer duration?**

The tickers themselves will not block the loop in any hidden way. The fastest ticker will always ensure the loop is looping at the speed of this ticker at least.

Note that the docs of `time.NewTicker` say:

> The ticker will adjust the time interval or drop ticks to make up for
> slow receivers

This just means, internally no new ticks are scheduled until you have consumed the last one from the single-element ticker channel.

In your example, the main pitfall is that any code in the `case` statements will block and thus delay the other cases.
If this is intended, everything is fine.

There may be other pitfalls if you have Microsecond or Nanosecond tickers where you may see some measurable runtime overhead or if you have hundreds of tickers and `case` blocks. But then you should have chose another scheduling pattern from the beginning.