# Why set a channel input parameter to nil?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I need some help making sense of the Go generics proposal [examples](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md).

In particular I am having trouble-so far-understanding two bits of code from the examples section of the proposal entitled "*Channels*":

The first point I don't get is found in the definition of `func Merge[T any](c1,c2 <-chan T) <-chan T`: the function instantiates a `chan T` variable that will hold the result and then it spins up a goroutine that will handle the actuall merging.

In particular, there is an infinite loop that runs as long as at least one of the input channels (to be merged) is not `nil`.

Code:

```
// Merge merges two channels of some element type into a single channel.
func Merge[T any](c1, c2 <-chan T) <-chan T {
    r := make(chan T)
    go func(c1, c2 <-chan T, r chan<- T) {
        defer close(r)
        for c1 != nil || c2 != nil {
            select {
            case v1, ok := <-c1:
                if ok {
                    r <- v1
                } else {
                    c1 = nil
                }
            case v2, ok := <-c2:
                if ok {
                    r <- v2
                } else {
                    c2 = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }(c1, c2, r)
    return r
}
```

In the loop, a `select` statement combs through the input channels for validly received values (the `vn,ok:=<-cn` expressions) and *then* comes the weird part:

If the channel sends valid values, merge and be done with it (`r<-vn`) **but** if the channel reports that it just supplied the zero value for its element type (`ok==false`) *then* the code in the `else` branch of both `case` branches does something *incomprehensible* (to me): it sets the channel variable to `nil`!

So, why does the merging goroutine is allowed to set its input channels to `nil`. Isn't this supposed to be the obligation of the goroutine that is responsible for input channels `cn`? I'm obviously missing something, please enlighten me.

Comment: It's just to exit the loop once both channels are `nil` (`for c1 != nil || c2 != nil { ...`). The caller's channel variables won't be `nil`. Setting an input parameter variable to `nil` will not modify the callers variable.

Comment: @mkopriva could it have used alternatively a `break` statement instead?

Comment: A `nil` channel blocks forever so the select case won't unnecessarily execute for such a channel. Setting them to `nil` is the correct approach for the purpose of that specific algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the channel to `nil` will prevent from that `case` getting executed from there on. Note: only the function parameter is set to `nil`, which is a local variable to the function, the channel object is left intact.

The function should loop until both input channels are closed, which will likely not happen at the same time. Once a channel is closed, receiving from it can proceed immediately. So if a channel is closed, the `case` receiving from it could be executed always from there on, *immediately*, unnecessarily using high CPU, and also it could prevent receiving from the other, non-closed channel (if multiple `case`s are ready, one is chosen pseudo-randomly, see [How does select work when multiple channels are involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645808/how-does-select-work-when-multiple-channels-are-involved/47648910#47648910)).

On the other hand, if a (closed) channel is set to `nil`, it will essentially be taken out from `select`, because receiving from a `nil` channel blocks forever (so only the other channel will be monitored from there on). For channel axioms, see [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004)