# When to use a finalizer to close a channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, finalizer

This is the second of two questions (this is the [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412598/why-set-a-channel-input-parameter-to-nil)) to help make sense of the Go generics proposal [examples](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md).

In particular I am having trouble-so far-understanding two bits of code from the examples section of the proposal entitled "*Channels*":

The second issue I have is in the following definition of the `Ranger` function.

Namely, I don't understand the need to call `runtime.SetFinalizer(r,r.finalize)` where in fact what the `finalize`) method of the `*Receiver[T]` type is supposed to do is simply to signal that the receiver is done receiving values (`close(r.done)`).

The way I see it, by providing a finalizer for a `*Receiver[T]` the code is delegating the obligation to close the receiver to the runtime.

The way I understand this piece of code, is that the `*Receiver[T]` signals to the `*Sender[T]` that it won't be receiving any more values when the GC decides that the former is unreachable ie no more references are available to it.

If my interpretation is correct, why wait that long for the receiver to signal it's done? Isn't it possible to explicitly handle the `close` operation in the code somehow?

Code:

```
// Ranger provides a convenient way to exit a goroutine sending values
// when the receiver stops reading them.
//
// Ranger returns a Sender and a Receiver. The Receiver provides a
// Next method to retrieve values. The Sender provides a Send method
// to send values and a Close method to stop sending values. The Next
// method indicates when the Sender has been closed, and the Send
// method indicates when the Receiver has been freed.
func Ranger[T any]() (*Sender[T], *Receiver[T]) {
    c := make(chan T)
    d := make(chan bool)
    s := &Sender[T]{values: c, done: d}
    r := &Receiver[T]{values: c, done: d}
    // The finalizer on the receiver will tell the sender
    // if the receiver stops listening.
    runtime.SetFinalizer(r, r.finalize)
    return s, r
}

// A Sender is used to send values to a Receiver.
type Sender[T any] struct {
    values chan<- T
    done   <-chan bool
}

// Send sends a value to the receiver. It reports whether any more
// values may be sent; if it returns false the value was not sent.
func (s *Sender[T]) Send(v T) bool {
    select {
    case s.values <- v:
        return true
    case <-s.done:
        // The receiver has stopped listening.
        return false
    }
}

// Close tells the receiver that no more values will arrive.
// After Close is called, the Sender may no longer be used.
func (s *Sender[T]) Close() {
    close(s.values)
}

// A Receiver receives values from a Sender.
type Receiver[T any] struct {
    values <-chan T
    done  chan<- bool
}

// Next returns the next value from the channel. The bool result
// reports whether the value is valid. If the value is not valid, the
// Sender has been closed and no more values will be received.
func (r *Receiver[T]) Next() (T, bool) {
    v, ok := <-r.values
    return v, ok
}

// finalize is a finalizer for the receiver.
// It tells the sender that the receiver has stopped listening.
func (r *Receiver[T]) finalize() {
    close(r.done)
}
```

Comment: "Is't it possible, to explicitly handle the close operation in the code somehow?" Yes, but the example is not about this but "Ranger provides a convenient way to exit a goroutine sending values when the receiver stops reading them." The whole point of this _example_ is do demonstrate that you can get around "to explicitly handle the close operation in the code somehow".

Comment: Note that the generics proposal is _not_ a good resource to learn generics. The proposal is full of edge cases, details and spezialist information. And: the proposal doesn't match the implementation.

Comment: @Volker I'd be really interested in alternative resources for generics in go, I was under the impression the proposal was accepted as is; what do mean the "proposal doesn't match the implementation"? are you referring to eg contracts or something else entirely? is there a source or sources one can refer to?

Comment: Most of the proposal is implemented, but the authorative thing is not the proposal but the language spec https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Your understanding is correct, the `done` channel may simply be closed by the receiver "manually" to signal the lost of interest (to stop the communication and relieve the sender from its duty).

---

Channels are used for goroutines to communicate in a concurrency safe manner. The idiomatic use is that the sender party keeps sending values, and once there are no more values to send, it is signaled by the sender closing the channel.

The receiver party keeps receiving from the channel until it is closed, which signals there won't be (can't be) any more values coming on the channel. This is usually / easiest done using a `for range` over the channel.

So *usually* the receiver has to keep receiving until the channel is closed, else the sender party would get blocked forever. Often this is OK / sufficient.

The demonstrated `Ranger()` construct is for the non-general case when there's need / possibility for the receiver to stop the communication.

A single channel does not provide a mean for the receiver party to signal the sender that the receiver has lost interest, and no more values are needed. This requires an additional channel which the receiver has to close (and the sender has to monitor of course). As long as there's a single receiver, this is also OK. But if there are multiple receivers, closing the `done` channel gets a little more complicated: it's not OK for all the receivers to close the `done` channel: closing an already closed channel panics. So the receivers also have to be coordinated, so only a single receiver, or rather the coordinator party itself closes the `done` channel, once only; and this has to happen after all receivers "abandoned" the channel.

`Ranger()` helps with this, and in a simple way by delegating closing the `done` channel using a finalizer. This is acceptable because usually it wouldn't even be the receiver(s) task to stop the communication, but in the rare case if this still arises, it will be dealt with (in an easy way, without the need of an additional, coordinator goroutine).